# Ext JS: Elements in Combo are not visible, but loaded

Tags: ajax, extjs, combobox, extjs6.2

Ext JS 6.2.x is used. A combo is created. It uses ajax proxy request:

```
Request .../rest/maps/tree?_dc=1519213286176&page=1&start=0&limit=25
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
```

In response body a set of years is returned:

```
["2015","2017","2018","2019","2016","2020"]
```

Here is a code:

```
Ext.define('MapsYears', {
    // extend: 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.maps-years',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['year'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'rest/maps/tree'
    }
});

Ext.define('Main.panel.SnapshotNow', {
    xtype: 'snapshotNow',
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires: [
    ],
    items: [{
        id: 'SnapshotNow',
        xtype: "combobox",
        store: {
            type: 'maps-years'
        },
        displayField: 'year',
        valueField: 'year'
    }]
});
```

Items are loaded, I can even click on the combo, and the item appears as a chosen, but a list of items is not visible:

[image: combo with not visible elements]

What do I miss?

**UPDATE:** In a response, it is not actually a json-format. I can fix this issue by changing rest service and returning a correct json. The question is, is there a way to tell ExtJS to process correctly list of elements in the original example, that looks like:

```
 ["2015","2017","2018","2019","2016","2020"]
```

Comment: How is the output of your ajax request? Can you show an example?

Comment: @EduardoMelzer, Response body is in the description. I've added also request and response headers.

Comment: Can you change the response to be `[["2015"],["2017"],["2018"],["2019"],["2016"],["2020"]]` ? If yes, then your can extend ArrayStore and you problem will be fixed. Also, set your combobox with `queryMode: 'local'`.

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes, thank you for your answer. the problem is that it forces me to change server side. the easiest and clear option in my case was to return a list of years. any additional effort on server side, in order to be able with ExtJS to process it, it is a wrong solution. Front end must not force back end to change the format. To make format more complicated. From my point of view.

Comment: @Alexandr ExtJS has ways for you to transform the data, I posted an answer that should help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your data structure

```
Ext.define('MapsYears', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.maps-years',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['year'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'rest/maps/tree',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            transform: data => data.map(year => ({year}))
        }
    }
});
```